# ODBCDataReader hangs randomly?

Tags: c#, ms-access, odbc, datareader

So, I have a huge query that I need to run on an Access DB. I am attempting to use a for loop to break it down because I can't run the query all at once (it has an IN with 50k values). The reader is causing all kinds of problems hanging and such. Most times when I break up the for loop into 50-10000 values the reader will read 400 (exactly 400) values and then hang for about 3 minutes then do another hundred or so, hang, ad infinium. If I do over 10k values per query it gets to 2696 and then hangs, does another 1k or so after hanging, on and on. I have never really worked with odbc, sql or any type of database for that matter, so it must be something stupid, or is this expected? Maybe there's a better way to do something like this? Here's my code that is looped:

```
//connect to mdb
OdbcConnection mdbConn = new OdbcConnection();
mdbConn.ConnectionString = @"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=C:\PINAL_IMAGES.mdb;";
mdbConn.Open();

OdbcCommand mdbCmd = mdbConn.CreateCommand();
mdbCmd.CommandText = @"SELECT RAW_NAME,B FROM 026_006_886 WHERE (B='CM1' OR B='CM2') AND MERGEDNAME IN" + imageChunk;
OdbcDataReader mdbReader = mdbCmd.ExecuteReader();

while (mdbReader.Read())
{
  sw.WriteLine(@"for /R %%j in (" + mdbReader[0] + @") do move %%~nj.tif .\" + mdbReader[1] + @"\done");
  linesRead++;
  Console.WriteLine(linesRead);
}
mdbConn.Close();
```

Here's how I populate the imageChunk variable for the IN by reading 5000 lines with a value line from a text file using a StreamReader:

```
                string imageChunk = "(";
                for (int j = 0; j < 5000; j++)
                {
                    string image;
                    if ((image = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        imageChunk += @"'" + sr.ReadLine() + @"',";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                imageChunk = imageChunk.Substring(0, imageChunk.Length - 1);
                imageChunk += ")";
```

Comment: Why have you an IN with 50K values? Why is this not in a table?

Comment: Because I'm a noob! Are you referring to DataTable?

Comment: No, I am not. I am referring to a table in Access. It is just not sensible to use IN for so many values. You need a join on a table.

Comment: I'm confused... the data is in a table "026_006_886" as shown above in the query.

Comment: You have two sets of data, the data in table 026_006_686 and the data in the IN statement. The data in the IN statement should also be in a table. The two tables can then be matched with an `INNER JOIN` to obtain the required result.

Comment: So create a table in memory just for the query? Right now the IN statement is created above in the added code (imageChunk).

Comment: A table in memory will not work with Access. You have already said that you cannot run the query all at once, I think you will find that a suitable table to limit the results will make the whole thing much easier and faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using a data adapter... Was slow but provided constant feedback instead of freezing up. Never really got a good answer why, but got some advice on smarter ways to perform a large query.

Comment: Your slowness probably has more to do with an inefficient query than an inefficient adapter (or lots of records). It's perfectly reasonable to expect 50k values to take less than a minute to return completely. Before you put your query into code, it's usually a good idea to try the query against the data directly - I'm not sure how you would do this, but in SQL, one might use SQL Management Studio to test the query.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection to the DB and execution of the querys seems ok to me. I suspect the "hanging" is coming because you are running the query multiple times. A couple of tips for speed. Columns B and MergedName should have indexes on them. Re-factoring your data table structure may also improve speed. Are you MergedNames truely random? If so you are probably stuck with the speed you have. As @Remou suggests, I would also compare total runtime of uploading your MergedNames list to a table, then joining the table to get your results, then delete your table on completion.

Comment: If the query is to be run more that once, it is better to delete the records than delete the table.